# Function checking for "deep equality" of nested objects

Tags: javascript, recursion, javascript-objects, deepequals

I am trying to write a function that checks if two objects have the same values. This function requires that I check for the equality of any objects that are stored as values inside the original objects. The approach I have developed (see code below) is to first check the equality of non-object values. Then, if these all match, I iterate over the objects again and make a recursive call to the original function, which allows me to compare each nested level of the two objects.

However, this approach only partially works. The nature of the recursive call means I can only check the equality of nested objects at the first key - value pair in the object. I cannot figure out how to check any additional key-value pairs containing nested objects once the first set of nested objects have been compared and the recursive call returns. Here is the function:

```
var deepEqual = function(val1, val2) {
  if (typeof val1 === 'object' && typeof val2 === 'object') {
      for (i in val1) {
        for (i in val2){
          if (typeof val1[i] !== 'object' && typeof val2[i] !== 'object') {
            if (val1[i] !== val2[i]) {
              return false
            }
          }
        }
      }
      for (i in val1) {
        for (i in val2){
          if (typeof val1[i] === 'object' && typeof val2[i] === 'object') {
            return deepEqual(val1[i], val2[i])
          }
        }
      }
    return true
  }
  else if (val1 === val2) {
    return true
  }
  else return false
}
```

My basic problem is that I believe I need a recursive call to check for the deep equality of nested objects, but that I can only do this check once successfully. Has anybody tried to solve a problem like this? I'll provide examples of my results for specific objects if you need more specific. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you don't care for property names? Btw, `for (i in val1) for (i in val2)` is disastrous.

Comment: I'm checking for values. Agree that the for loops are not optimal - bear with me, I'm an inexperienced programmer, this was my first pass through this problem

Comment: So you would expect `{a:1, b:2}` and `{a:2, b:1}` to be equal (as they contain the same values)?

Comment: Have you considered just using a JSON.stringify on your two objects and comparing if their strings are equal? Not knowing exactly what constitutes equality or the structure of your objects, I only posted this as a comment. If this approach has any value I will upgrade to an answer.

Comment: Sorry, no. I care for the property names. I misundestood your first question. As an example, `var val1 = {"city": "Seattle", "name": {"first": {"Ben": "Benny"}}, "country": "USA", "firstname": {"first": {"Ben": "Bedanny"}}}
var val2 = {"city": "Seattle", "name": {"first": {"Ben": "Benny"}}, "country": "USA", "firstname": {"first": {"Ben": "Benny"}}}` should return false, but it returns true (as the second set of nested objects are never checked because the function returns true if the first set of nested objects are the same.

Comment: @mccaniz I hadn't though of this - let me try it out

Comment: @mccainz Yes - the JSON.stringify approach works. Thanks!

Comment: In regards to @mccainz solution, this will only work if the objects are initialized in the exact same way. If the properties are the same but in a different order, it will fail. This might be enough for you, but just an FYI.

Comment: @Bergi - BTW, could you give me a hint on a way to scan the two objects without using so many for loops? As I mentioned, I'm an inexperienced JS programmer.

Comment: @Jan - thanks, I agree this is fairly brittle, but it is fine for my current purposes.

Comment: I would suggest you read up a bit on loops and recursion to start with. Then draw out a schema on paper of what you want to perform and how you'd go about doing that. Also, maybe start with something smaller. And search SO, there are surely plenty solutions to similar problems.

Comment: Well, `return deepEqual(val1[i], val2[i])` should obviosly be `if (!deepEqual(val1[i], val2[i])) return false` just as you did it in your first loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to  JSON stringify the objects and compare their string representations. As @Jan mentions ...

> this will only work if the objects are initialized in the exact same
>   way. If the properties are the same but in a different order, it will
>   fail

...this is a bit brittle but may suit your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution, but I recommend you find your own, really.

```
function isEqual(var1, var2) { // Break the comparison out into a neat little function
  if (typeof var1 !== "object") {
    return var1===var2;
  } else {
    return deepEqual(var1, var2);
  }
}

function deepEqual(var1, var2) {
   for (i in var1) { 
      if(typeof var2[i] === "undefined") { // Quick check, does the property even exist?
         return false;
      }
      if (!isEqual(var1[i], var2[i])) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}

function areObjectsEqual(obj1, obj2) {
   return deepEqual(obj1, obj2) && deepEqual(obj2, obj1); // Two-way checking
}
```

You not only need to check if everything in `obj1` exists in `obj2`, but also that everything in `obj2` exists in `obj1`. This solution entails doing the comparison both ways, but you could optimize this greatly.

And some test cases

```
var v1 = { obj0:"jan", obj:{ name:"jan"}, obj2:"ben" }
var v2 = { obj:{ name:"jan"}, obj2:"ben" }

console.log(areObjectsEqual(v1, v2))

v1 = { obj:{ name:"jan"}, obj2:"ben" }
v2 = { obj:{ name:"jan"}, obj2:"ben" }

console.log(areObjectsEqual(v1, v2))

v1 = { obj:{ name:"jan2"}, obj2:"ben" }
v2 = { obj:{ name:"jan"}, obj2:"ben" }

console.log(areObjectsEqual(v1, v2))

v1 = { obj:{ name:"jan"}, obj2:"ben" }
v2 = { obj:{ name:"jan"}, obj2:"ben", obj3:"pig" }

console.log(areObjectsEqual(v1, v2))
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this - the instruction I had for the problem was to do this in one function - but this definitely makes sense. Thanks for your work on this!

Comment: What a horrible instruction... That's not how you want to code, yuch.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is `_.isEqual` from the `lodash` or `underscore` library.

There is also the `deepEqual` test from the `Chai.js` assertion library.