# Recursive swearing function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've just learned what recursion is from watching 5 videos on YouTube.

The idea is much clearer, but not clear enough I guess as my own recursive function only shows swear word once in the console.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/05xxxbet/

```
/*
*     @param {string} swear - your insult
*     @param {number} times - how many times to repeat
*/
var recursiveSwear = function(swear, times){
    if(times == 1)
        return swear;
    else
        return recursiveSwear(swear, times - 1);
};

console.log(recursiveSwear("You bastard!", 6));

// Desired output:
//  You Bastard!
//  You Bastard!
//  You Bastard!
//  You Bastard!
//  You Bastard!
//  You Bastard!

//Actual output:
//  You Bastard!
```

Comment: Describe exactly what you expect. Multiple separate logs? A single log with multiple words? Something else?

Comment: I think foremost OP wants to understand what they're doing wrong. The top answers explain that pretty well.

Comment: @Jan: Nothing is done wrong. There's a recursive function executing until the base case is reached. What's wrong could only be a deficiency of the result which the OP expects, yet has not stated.

Comment: From context, OP expects their output to be repeated (any which way). With that goal they were doing something wrong. The question is more about understanding how something works than reaching an exact result, so the exact result isn't that important.

Comment: @Jan: Considering that it works perfectly in its recursion, I'd say the goal is very important. If he's expecting a single string of that phrase concatenated together, then the answer that shows mere `console.log()` calls per  recursive call would be of no value. Clearly, the result is the only thing missing.

Comment: I wouldn't say no value. They explain that some action has to be taken inside the recursion for it to have an effect (other than increasing the time taken for execution of the script).

Comment: @Jan: He knows that *some action* needs to be taken. Hence the question. Without us knowing the desired result, we can't know which action he needs to meet his goals.

Comment: ...and his comment under the accepted answer shows that he wanted something specific, though his updated question seems to contradict it.

Comment: My take on it was that they should be appended and logged as one, otherwise you may as well use a simple loop - the recursion would be pointless.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Why would it be pointless?

Comment: Because you could have just done `for (var x =0;x<6;x++) console.log(swear)` - it's not a problem that would need to be solved using recursion.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Isn't the recursion pointless either way? There's no particular benefit to the recursion here. Recursion would be more beneficial if it doubled the string whenever the `times` is an even number. Then it would be more efficient.

Comment: @squint If just logging a string multiple times, yes - I wouldn't use recursion.  But since the OP is attempting to use it as a way of _learning_ recursion, actually using it in a fashion relevant to recursion (by using the current value and the returned value of a recursive call as per my answer) isn't _entirely_ pointless.

Comment: @JamesThorpe

Hmm. Couldn't you say the same about the looping method? "Couldn't you have just done it recursively?"

Comment: @BaddieProgrammer You could, yes.  But I bet most people wouldn't.

Comment: @JamesThorpe
Why not? Why do you say this problem doesn't need to be solved by recursion? It could be.

Comment: @BaddieProgrammer I'd say there's nothing wrong with doing this to learn. But to clarify, here's an example of a problem that DOES require recursion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101894/function-checking-for-deep-equality-of-nested-objects/31102466#31102466

Comment: At that point it starts to get opinion based, but I think the recursive way is harder to read/maintain.  I would also guess it's probably less performant

Comment: Here's a recursive version that cuts down on the calls. This is more efficient than one (recursive or not) that simply adds the original string one at a time. http://jsfiddle.net/Lsjmvw5e/ Or perhaps more clear with a separate variable. http://jsfiddle.net/Lsjmvw5e/1/

Comment: @JamesThorpe

I guess that's your opinion. I'll leave it at that then.

Comment: @squint Weird. If I pass `-1` for `times` it prints anyways.

Comment: @BaddieProgrammer: Yeah, didn't have negative numbers in mind. The first condition doesn't need to handle `1` since it's handled by the second condition, so it should just return an empty string if `<= 0`. http://jsfiddle.net/Lsjmvw5e/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing recursive work, you often need use the current value in conjunction with return value of the recursive call.  In this case, you can append them as follows:

```
var recursiveSwear = function(swear, times){
    if(times == 1)
        return swear;
    else
        return swear + ' ' + recursiveSwear(swear, times - 1);
};

console.log(recursiveSwear("Oh darn!~", 6));
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the only answer whose code actually shows multiple swears instead of just one in the log.

Comment: Is it possible that for the others you're seeing one log entry with a "6" to the left? That means it was logged 6 times.

Comment: @Jan
Doesn't look like it. Just print's insult twice no matter the `times` value provided.

Comment: Ok, if you are using firefox the number is on the right, not left. It DOES print six times.

Comment: @BaddieProgrammer I'm really sorry but other answers (including mine) too show the desired num of "Swears"!

Comment: Just don't ask it not to swear. It might be insulted and start swearing uncontrollably (but silently).

Comment: @Jan Mm. No. And I'm using Firefox.

Comment: @Jan Hm. No. Nothing.

Answer (score 4):

your function is fine but you are not logging "swears"

```
var recursiveSwear = function(swear, times){
    if(times == 1)
        return swear;
    else
        console.log(swear); //log them here
        return recursiveSwear(swear, times - 1);
};

console.log(recursiveSwear("Shut up!", 6));
```

Answer (score 2):

The body of your recursive function doesn't actually have any kind of output. Shouldn't you move your `console.log` inside the `else` clause? e.g.:

```
var recursiveSwear = function(swear, times){
  if(times == 1)
      return swear;
  else {
      console.log(swear);
      return recursiveSwear(swear, times - 1);
  }
};
```

Comment: As it stands your function is an infinite loop.